# how to implement the create new password functionality directly from user's email

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the scenario in which a new user has been created in my application by Admin.

1st step will be
user has allotted by a temporary password
and receives the email with an activation link

User will just by clicking on that link taken to the create new password page , he creates his new password and thats it.

Now my query is how will the application knows that which user is this ,just by clicking that activation link in his email

Comment: sounds like you need some sort of random unique key associated with the user and sent to them in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Activation links carry a long token, such as `activate.jsp?tok=98357627272357852786276258763427934579342579342793426734279`. This token can be randomly selected, and stored in a database. When the page is loaded, the token is looked up, and the correct user gets authenticated. The token may then be deleted from the database.

Comment: In that scenario, you could omit the `user=uname` request parameter, couldn't you?

Comment: @mthmulders Yes, though often that parameter is used in practice.

Comment: +1 and even though obvious I would like to remind to reset the token immediately (delete it) when the new password is successfully entered so that no one can use it to change password for that account after that.

Comment: Also a nice idea is to have the token invalidated automatically after (say) 24 hours if not used.

Comment: thanks ,it would be a basic question but .. I can send the token with the link .. then if the user clicks on the link..it will be something like mysiteName/createpasswordPage?tok=89799...   So how will i ignore this token while opening a page..because if i use this token inside the link..my page will not open..Secondly how will i fetch the token  from the link to compare it with db token..

Comment: @junaidp Parameters? It's nothing more than a parameter. Read up more on JSP and dynamic programming for web in general.